# The apk must be signed with the same certificates as the previous

Tags: android, certificate, keystore

I'm trying to uploading an update of one of my apps, I've created a new project on eclipse starting from the old version of the app, the app use the same package and the same key for signing but I still get this error **The apk must be signed with the same certificates as the previous**

how can I solve this? I'm sure that the key is the same as the old version. The only thing I did is to update the app using ActionBarSherlock

Thanks

Comment: Are you signing with a release key? or a letting eclipse sign it with the default debug key?

Comment: i'm using the release key, i've also tried to use jar signer and zipalign manually but i have the same error

Answer (score 3):

I am sure there is a problem here which is not being addressed. I made the one keystore to be used for all my apps and am quite sure I would not have created a new one for no reason whatever and then deleted it without remembering. I can't imagine that all of the umpteen people on 8+ pages of Google with the same story are all idiots either.

I have just compared CERT.RSA from the old APK with that of a newly created APK of another project signed using my keystore and Windiff reports different in blanks only. I would assume that proves the same keystores were used.

I created a new APK for the problem project and compared the CERT.RSA with the others and there are two extra encoded lines present. These extra lines are also not present in the CERT.RSA of another project exported using a different keystore, the file structure of that is the same.

Here is the difference:
http://www.gatekeeperel.co.uk/image_files/image1.jpg

There were all created in the same way - Rt Click/Export/Export Android Application/Use existing keystore in Eclipse.

Does anyone have any idea what is going on? Really. I really have no confidence whatever in being able to update apps in future. Ta for any ideas.

Comment: Have you learned anything more about what's going on? I'm pretty confident I'm using the same keystore, but I'm getting the "different certs" error when updating. Feeling kind of desperate...

Answer (score 2):

I'm also having the same problem.  I ran the jarsigner tool

jarsigner.exe -verify -verbose -certs C:\apkfilename.apk

for the old apk and a newly created one and the output is the same other than the dates of the res/drawables.

I am 100% sure that the keystore, alias, and password is the same.